# Find the derivative using the chain rule and the quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> $$f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^4$$ Find $f'(x)$.

Here is my work:

$$f'(x) = \frac{4x^3\left(x+1\right)^4-4\left(x+1\right)^3x^4}{\left(x+1\right)^8}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{4x^3\left(x+1\right)^4-4x^4\left(x+1\right)^3}{\left(x+1\right)^8}$$

I know the final simplified answer to be:

$${4x^3\over (x+1)^5}$$

**How do I get to the final answer from my last step?** Or have I done something wrong in my own work?

Comment: You have written down $f' = (f')^4$! Remove that excess power.

Comment: Ah, I see it. editing..

Comment: Wait, where do I remove it from? the first (x+1) in the top, or from the general equation?

Comment: Your edited equation for $f'$ is now right. Cancel immediately $(x+1)^3$ from the numerator and denominator, and simplify.

Comment: Makes sense now, thank-you.

Comment: Note that you can simplify $x/(x+1)$ to $(x+1-1)/(x+1) = 1-(x+1)^{-1}$ which you might find easier to differentiate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You calculation of $f'(x)$ is correct, though it can be simplified. To do this, we factor out $4x^3(x+1)^3\require{cancel}$ in the numerator.

$$\begin{align}f'(x) &= \frac{4x^3(x+1)^4-4x^4(x+1)^3}{(x+1)^8}\\\\
&= \frac{\color{blue}{4x^3(x+1)^3}\Big((x+1) - x\Big)}{(x+1)^8}\\\\
&= \frac {(4x^3\cancel{(x+1)^3})(1)}{\cancel{(x+1)^8}^5}\\ \\
&= \frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^5}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, McB!

Answer (score 6):

it is easier to use logarithmic differentiation on this problem. here is how you do this. $$y = \left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^4 \to \ln y = 4 \ln x - 4 \ln x + 1\to \frac{dy}{y} =4\left(\frac{dx}{x} - \frac{dx}{x+1} \right) = \frac{4dx}{x(x+1)} $$ multiplying through by $y$ gives you $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^5} $$

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen it done like that.

Comment: @McB, you are welcome. it makes it easier to get a simpler expression than the product and quotient rule. with $\ln,$ multiplication becomes addition; addition is much easier than multiplication to handle. i like the picture you have. a great person.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you complicated things too much.

Starting from $$f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^4$$ with the chain rule we get first 
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 4\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^3\cdot \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^\prime\notag\\
&= 4\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^3\cdot \frac{x'(x+1)-x(x+1)'}{(x+1)^2}\notag\\
&= 4\frac{x^3}{(x+1)^3}\cdot \frac{(x+1)-x}{(x+1)^2}\notag\\
&= \frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^3}\cdot \frac 1{(x+1)^2}\notag\\
&= \frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^5}\notag
\end{align}

Comment: This seems to be the most appropriate answer because it makes proper use of chain rule. +1 I have edited the latex code to make the equation looks aligned.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I usually try to avoid the quotient rule if possible.

$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^4 = \left(\frac{x+1-1}{x+1}\right)^4 = \left(\frac{x+1}{x+1} + \frac{-1}{x+1}\right)^4 = \left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)^4 $$

Applying the chain rule yields

$$ f'(x) = 4 \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^3 \cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} = 4 \cdot \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^3 \cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} = 4 \cdot \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^3} \cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^5} $$

Comment: very smart  way to avoid cumbersome quotient rule +1

Answer (score 1):

Not wrong, only written in a different form: you can simplify much of it.

It's much better exploiting the chain rule: if you call
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{x+1},
$$
then $f(x)=(g(x))^4$ and so
$$
f'(x)=4(g(x))^3g'(x)=
4\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\!3}\frac{1(x+1)-x\cdot 1}{(x+1)^2}=
\frac{4x^3}{(x+1)^5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First use the chain rule
$$(4*x^3)/(x+1)^3$$........(*)
Now derivate the inner function finding using quotient rule
$$((X+1)-x)/(x+1)^{2}=> 1/(x+1)^{2}$$.........(${*}{*}$)
Now multiply them both (*) &. (**) to get
&$${4x^{3}}/{(x+1)^{5}}$$

Comment: If you want this to be an answer rather than a comment, you should (1) flesh it out and (2) use mathjax to render it prettily.